# t string error in if statement in function

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting this error:

**PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING**

For this line:

```
if($email_addr == "") /* If real email not found, return FALSE*/
```

I can't figure out what is wrong and tried so many things and researched for two days with no correction.  I wonder if anyone else can see what I am doing wrong.  Why am I getting this error?  Thank you.  (the function is below)

```
    function searchRecipient() // function to search the database for the real email
{
    global $MessageSentToMailbox; // bring in the alias email
    $email_addr = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM tbl WHERE source='$MessageSentToMailbox'"); // temp store of the real email
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($email_addr); //making temp store of data for use in program
    if($email_addr == "") /* If real email not found, return FALSE*/
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else  /* Else, return find the person's name and return both in an array */
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE email = '$email_addr'"; // pulling in the row where the emails match
        $results = mysql_query($query, $email_addr); // temp store of both queries from this function
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results); //making temp store of data for use in program
        $name = $row['author'];  // taking the author data and naming its variable
        return array($name, $email_addr);  // this is the name and the real email address to be used in function call
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a resource to a string.

What you really mean to do is this:

```
if ($row['email']== "")
```

Or, even better this:

```
if (empty($row['email']))
```

Comment: That isn't a syntax error though. The original code is syntactically correct, as a lint check verifies.

Comment: Never said it was a syntax error. I just said it was an error. :)

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong.  I had tried your first one before as well and no success.  I just tried your second one and still no success!  I did find a solution but then the next line had the error.  The next line was only the curly bracket.  I don't understand and can't think of any other solutions.

Comment: Might be a quotes issue somewhere above it

Comment: I moved the function to the top of the page and still got the error.  I also went through all the quotes to make sure they were right as well.  I will do it again though.  Thanks.

Comment: I still can't get it to work.  I even took the function out of the program script and put it in another file and still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($row['email']== "") /* If real email not found, return FALSE*/
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
```